# How to wait for a Recaptcha to load in Pyppeteer?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, puppeteer, browser-automation, pyppeteer

I want to scrape a website and I'm having difficulties with the Recaptcha. I've already figured out a way to solve it but before that method starts I have to make sure Recaptcha is fully loaded, which is what I'm stuck at.
I've tried `page.waitForSelector('#captchaFormPart > td:nth-child(2) > script:nth-child(1)', options={'visible': True})` and it didn't work.

Comment: Can someone answer?